# Can I run Heavy Windows Software on Wine in UBUNTU 18.04?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe, video-editor

I want to use Premiere Pro CC 2017 in my Ubuntu laptop but I am not sure that it will work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't run well. You can always check it at [winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=128&sClass=application)

Most likely it won't run at all.

The new version seems not to run at all, older ones more or less are "garbage".

Comment: Yeah man, that's what I thought.